# Relationship between a main entity and one of many unrelated entities?

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005, xquery, entity-relationship

I have a bridge table that defines a relationship between a main entity and one of many unrelated entities. In order to do this, the table has the following columns:

ID, MAIN_ENTITY_ID, ENTITY_TYPE, ENTITY_1_ID, ENTITY_2_ID, ..., ENTITY_N_ID

where ENTITY_1_ID, ENTITY_2_ID, ..., ENTITY_N_ID are foreign keys to their respective tables. The ENTITY_TYPE column lets me know which entity in particular a main entity is related to.

Some of the disadvantage of using this scheme are:

- Most of the columns of the row are null, since they're mutually exclusive.
- Every time a new entity is added, I have to add a new type, and a new column to the table.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this, maybe to have an xml column to do the relation the other entities.. or maybe the way I do is the best solution for now..

Answer (score 4):

XML is not something I would recommend for this. You can not enforce a foreign key in a XML column.

You can have one bridge table for each entity table.
Every time you add a new entity table you also have to add a new bridge table for that entity type.

Comment: @Artemination Perhaps. But then you need a trigger on the bridge table and on all entity tables as well right? You need to prevent an update of the PK in the entity table if it exist a XML with that value used and you need to prevent a delete of a used entity as well alternatively your trigger has to do cascade delete and cascade update. Depending the number of rows you have in the bridge table those checks might take some time.